# log4j2 not logging to console, file or syslog

Tags: java, servlets, logging, log4j2

I am struggling to get log4j2 to do any sort of logging.  Even if I turn up log4j config to trace level I don't get any trace to debug with.

This is using (or rather attempting to use) servlets 2.5 and log4j 2.1

I am a little bit lost as for the reason why because I've followed all the docs as far as I can tell ?

```
    package myPkg;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.web.WebLoggerContextUtils;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {
    final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyResource.class);
    logger.debug("test");

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
   logger.debug("test");
        logger.info("INFO");
        logger.warn("WARN");
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

I have implemented changes in web.xml as per the docs, relevant extract is as follows :

```
   <!-- log4j-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>log4jServletFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>log4j Context Name</description>
    <param-name>log4jContextName</param-name>
    <param-value>myWeb</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>log4j Configuration File Location</description>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
    <param-value>file:///home/ME/testConfig/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
    <!-- end log4j-->
```

And my pom.xml for log4j looks like

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

And my log4j.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
<!-- STDOUT -->
<Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
<PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
</Console>
<!-- DEBUG FILE -->
<File name="debugFile" fileName="/home/ME/testConfig/debug.log">
<ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
<ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
<PatternLayout>
<Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
</PatternLayout>
</File>
<!-- SYSLOG -->
<Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="514"
protocol="TCP" appName="VoIP" includeMDC="true"
facility="LOCAL0" enterpriseNumber="43053" newLine="true"
messageId="Audit" id="App"/>
<!-- DO LOGGING -->
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<Root level="trace">
<AppenderRef ref="debugFile" level="TRACE"/>
<AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" level="WARN"/>
<AppenderRef ref="RFC5424" level="INFO"/>
</Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI there appears to be a bug in log4j2.1 whereby if you have whitespace ahead of the XML header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) it will silently die !

Comment: I had the same issue with 2.5, over 2.2 and it turns out, in 2.2 log4j.properties worked whereas in 2.5 it must be log4j.xml. When it failed, it failed silently. I believe this is a bug.